# JavaFX full screen problem on a CentOS without desktop environment

Tags: javafx, centos, fullscreen, xorg

For my case I'm not able to give much detail for a start due to different reasons, but I decided to go straight to the point and ask. First I'd like to point out that this is a very specific question, to prevent unrelated general answers.

For a kiosk JavaFX 8 application that needs to be run on CentOS 6.10 without a desktop environment, but only with XOrg / X-Server for graphics support, there seems no way to prevent that an initial login window goes full screen. This login window's layout is defined via FXML as a medium sized rectangle which works fine on a desktop suited environment, without code differences.  I have tried to call Stage's `setWidth()` and `setHeight()` methods (planning to try `max` variants soon) before and after showing it via `show()` method.

Does anyone have any quick idea about what issue could be causing this at first glance? I may provide other details on demand. Nonetheless, I will post any solution I come up with.

Thanks

EDIT: The current XOrg version on the affected machine seems to be `xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.17.4-17.el6.centos.i686`

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  You want to display a window without a [window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager)?

Comment: You are understanding it correcly. I don't have much idea about this topic (X sessions and such), and I was sure there should be a way to achieve this without a window manager. For instance, I can see windowed dialogs working using `JOptionPane` from Swing API, even when they don't have decorations (minimize/maximize/close buttons, or native window borders). I have tried to embed JavaFX views into Swing using the following: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html, but basically it didn't work even when using all possible methods to force the desired dimensions.

Comment: This is very interesting. I'm trying to do a similar thing but my problem is that I can't get full screen, the window only covers a small rectangle little above the vertical center of the screen, it's perfectly usable but too small. May I ask you how you managed to do it?

Comment: @Nand I'm not sure what's your exact question. However, if you mean how I embedded my JavaFX view with Swing, I did a simple class to make such requests, that looks more or less like [this](https://gist.github.com/Adrianilloo/401845b50514df7095bd43ad97436854). It simply requires to pass a valid `Scene` to the custom `wrap` function. Also, you don't have to use an `Stage` at all, like usually, since that's replaced by Swing' base window layout system.

So, this sample is working on a normal desktop environment but not on my desired machine as exposed in the initial post.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the sample code referenced in my previous comment results at the problematic CentOS machine in a full screen white window without any content (whereas the embedded `Scene` I'm using has elements defined). Hint: could migrating the whole app. presentation to Swing be the only way to go? I think there must be some other way around...

Comment: Oh, then our problems aren't the same. My app works but it's too small. I doubt you would have to migrate to Swing to get it work. I'm going to try wrapping my JavaFX stage in a Swing Frame and see what happens. EDIT: Wrapping it with swing didn't work for me (same size, not large enough) so I'm going to stop cluttering your comments with my unrelated issue.

Comment: I fixed my issue by setting the stage x/y/width/height manually.

Comment: Alright. Regarding my issue, I have set up a similar environment on a VM, running Centos 6.10 minimal with "X Window System" package group and Oracle's JDK 8 installed. After making a simple JavaFX demo application with two windows, the result is the [following](https://mega.nz/#!LgpBQCTS!CwEKQItOb46DoLk2R-PF5ZKPV3m8nfWF90XgqONEN7E). I made a repository available with this demo, which contains comments regarding layout calls and their correct order for best integration practices on JavaFX embedding into Swing, [here](https://github.com/Adrianilloo/JavaFXOverSwing.git).

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working for you without Swing, have you tried setting x/y/width/height manually on the JavaFX Stage? My test was on Ubuntu 19 so that might be the case. I also have LXDE installed (but not using, just not removed yet) so it might have pulled in some dependency that affects this. I use Liberica JDK 13 64-bit because I wasn't able to get original OpenJFX working on that device.

Comment: Finally found the solution. Problem [had nothing to do with JavaFX itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59629028/6855606). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Problem (forced full screen windows) was caused by an existing invokation to [dwm](https://dwm.suckless.org/) within `.xinitrc` file, used for a different existing application